# add throbber by start() function instead of show() element

Tags: javascript, jquery, throbber

This code adds a gif throbber:

```
function glitch_player_display(arg1,arg2) {
        jQuery('#loader').show(); // show loading...
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxglitch_playerajax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'ajaxglitch_player_ajaxhandler',
            arg1: arg1,
            arg2: arg2
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            var loadpostresult = '#showglitchplayer';
            jQuery(showglitchplayer).html('');
            jQuery(showglitchplayer).append(data);
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<img src="js/ajax-loader.gif" id="loader" style="display:none;"/>
```

However I want to use [this throbber by function](http://aino.github.io/throbber.js/)

This is the code I'm trying

```
function glitch_player_display(arg1,arg2) {
        var throb = Throbber();
        throb.appendTo( document.getElementById( 't1' ) );
        throb.start();
                    jQuery.ajax({//etc as above
```

the HTML

```
<div id="t1" class="throb"></div>
```

The throbber.js code is added to the .js document and am not getting any errors in console, but no throbber either. Am I calling it incorrectly? And once it is called correctly, what will be the equivilent of `$('#loader').hide()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the throbber! It was there the whole time. A white throbber in a white background. Hiding.

And stopping it was a matter of adding `throb.stop();` upon `success:` (where `$('#loader').hide();` is, in the code above).

Throbber.js is sweet.